# Yosemite, target deployement with gfortran

Tags: osx-yosemite, gfortran

On OS X Yosemite, this works:

```
gfortran main.f90
```

But this:

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5 gfortran main.f90
```

yields to the error:

```
ld: library not found for -lcrt1.10.5.o
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Why?

gfortran has been installed from http://hpc.sourceforge.net/, file gfortran-4.9-bin.tar.gz .

I use `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5` in order to create binaries that run on OS X from 10.5 to 10.10

I have the file `/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib/crt1.10.5.o`

Maybe something related to statically linked binary: [apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/qa/qa1118/_index.html).

**Edit:**

This works:

```
MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5 gfortran -o main -L/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/lib main.f90
```

But is it the right way? Is it a problem that `crt1.10.5.o` is linked statically?

Comment: `crt1.10.5.o` contains the entry point of the application and some start-up code for the C library. It is supposed to be linked statically. Note that `crt1.o` is not the same as `crt0.o`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this for compiling with gfortran by installing XCode command-line tools as described http://hpc.sourceforge.net
Not sure it will solve your problem.
Good luck.
Jon